# iOS + PHP - Extracting sum of money from Apple IAP

Tags: php, ios

I am developing an iOS app that uses Apple's in-app purchase service.
I am also developing a PHP backend service that, upon purchase, receives the encoded receipt string, validates it with Apple's validation servers, and saves the purchase record in the DB.

I would like to know, from the server side, either the product's price, or the sum of money that the user has actually paid for the product.

I prefer to get the result in USD, but any currency would be great as long as I have a way of knowing which currency it is (i.e. currency symbol as part of the string) so I can convert it.

The JSON object that returns from the validation doesn't contain the sum of money that has been paid in the transaction, or the product's price. Is there any way of getting this information from the receipt string only? Or perhaps from the product ID or transaction ID (both can be extracted from the receipt)? Or does this information have to be supplied by the app?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone is interested, after some more digging around the internet - it seems impossible...

So I just send the price that was paid by the user (stored in the SKProduct object), in local currency, along with the receipt, to the server. On the server, I convert the sent price to USD and store it.

Another method I have considered was to store a JSON on the server with all of the product IDs as keys, and their prices in USD as values. Then, once the receipt is validated, I can get the product ID from the receipt and the price from the JSON.
Please note that this solution may not give you the exact amount of money that the user has actually paid, because product prices and taxes may slightly differ between app stores in different countries. This solution is good for getting an estimated price only.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What do you do if the price changed between the time of initial purchase and autorenewal? You won;t be able to know which sum will be used upon autorenewal

Comment: Good question @DataGreed . At the time I only needed this mechanism for one-time purchases (consumable and non-consumable items). For subscriptions you would need to store a history of price changes. Perhaps compare the sum that was initially paid with the one you have stored to get an estimation of the tax, and then use that tax to calculate the actual sum with the updated price?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the actual amount paid isn't included in the receipt (keys are listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1)).

However, the price is included in the `SKProduct` object and the product identifier is available in the receipt, so you could send all the prices to your server when you send the receipt, and use the product identifier in the receipt to get the corresponding price.

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSMutableDictionary *prices = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (SKProduct *product in [response products]) {

        NSString *productIdentifier = [product productIdentifier];
        NSDecimalNumber *price = [product price];
        NSLocale *priceLocale = [product priceLocale];

        prices[productIdentifier] = @[price, priceLocale];
    }

    // keep these in memory and send them with the receipt
}
```

Comment: I have actually thought about something like this - storing the prices in USD in the server config JSON. A solution like this seems a bit sloppy at scale. Too much data transferred, too many copies of the same data, too many searches in arrays/hashes, etc...
I currently just send the amount of money that was paid from the client (in local currency) and convert it on the server.